# Preloading Strict Transport Security (HSTS)

Tags: ssl, web-server, configuration

I configured my webserver to use [Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). 
 I more or less used a configuration as in [this manual](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_for_Apache_NGINX_and_Lighttpd.html). 
But I get the following in my SSL-report if I run a test on [Qualys SSL LABS](https://www.ssllabs.com):

[image]

Why is the report stating that it won't do HSTS Preloading for those browsers:

> Not in: Chrome  Edge  Firefox  IE  Tor

How can I change this? I saw this for another website, so it should be possible:

[image]

Comment: See https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HSTS preload is a list of sites that are hard coded into Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE 11 and Edge as being HTTPS only.

You can include a domain in to the HSTS preload list in https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

see more:

[Preloading HSTS Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2012/11/01/preloading-hsts/)
[HTTP Strict Transport Security comes to Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 and Windows 7](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/09/http-strict-transport-security-comes-to-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-8-1-and-windows-7/)

Comment: For others: be aware that this process is not easily undo-able!